# How to switch to python 2.7 from python 3- jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am running a Jupyter notebook instance and it has both python 2 and python 3 kernels. However, when i use the python 2 kernel and execute below statements,

```
import sys
sys.executable
```

I get python 3 path

```
'/usr/bin/python3.4'
```

How do i force it to use python 2.7

[image]

Comment: If you haven't done already restart the Kernel in the Kernel dropdown menu. If that isn't the problem I would just reinstall the kernel. You are not using Conda by any chance?

Comment: Re-installing jupyter using pip instead of pip3 is what worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re-installing Jupyter with pip instead of pip3 is what worked